# Setting Shift + Spacebar + SomeLetter as an alternative for arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Is there any way to customize your keyboard to set <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>SomeLetter</kbd> as an alternative for arrow keys? When editing text, I either use a mouse or arrow keys to take the cursor to a particular location within some line. Both methods are very restrictive as they make me lose my focus and slow me down.

If I am correct, using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> has no particular allocation and it just prints the typical `space`. Combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are often assigned to some other tasks. So it is good to be able to define such a shortcut globally. Is it possible (and do you recommend) to do that? I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I know how to set global commands for applications/programs, but I do not know how to accomplish this job (if possible).

This is how I can add shortcuts in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: What editor are you using?  Have you considered learning Vim?  https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cross posting (posting the exact same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites) is **strongly** discouraged.  I recommend you delete one or the other of the two questions.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code. It is the first editor I have ever used for programming. I just started to learn working with texteditors.

Comment: If you can set "global" desktop shortcuts, can you set one to send an arrow key?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I will remove the other one.

Comment: I added an image to my question on how I can add shortcuts for `commands`.

Comment: I would think that particular combination is impossible. I don't know the exact terminology, but Ctrl and Shift and Alt are modifier keys -- space is not. It's like asking if you can press A and B simultaneously and get some other char typed. Shift+Space+A will result in a space and an A being typed.

Comment: @glennjackman it’s possible in Vim and emacs.

Comment: Vi has key cusror movemnt on letter keys (`H` `J` `K` `L` ) , but you need to press escape after inserting text. Emacs has cursor movement on ctrl+letter (`P` `N` `F` `B` ). so if you're using somethig with VI or emacs compatability (vim, emacs. xemacs, joe, jed etc) there's a near compatible feature there already.

Comment: @Jasen, you can set up shortcuts in Vim that work in insert mode, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, I used <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>.

Based on the accepted answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510024/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-create-new-keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu), I created a keyboard layout based in the English (UK). If your keyboard is not English UK you might have to change the key codes in the file. This keyboard layout maps the arrow keys to

- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> = left
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> = down
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> = right
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = up
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> = prev page
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> = next page
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> = home
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> = end
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> = backspace
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> = delete
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> = escape
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> = insert

It also maps numbers to the right hand:

- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> = 0
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> = 1
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> = 2
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> = 3
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> = 4
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> = 5
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> = 6
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> = 7
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> = 8
- <kbd>alt gr</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> = 9

Copy the following text into a new file to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/aa`

```
// based on a keyboard map from an 'xkb/symbols/gb' file

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "mylayout" {

// Describes the differences between a very simple en_US
// keyboard and a very simple U.K. keyboard layout defined by
// MyLayout

include "latin"

name[Group1]="MyLayout (UK)";

key <AE02>  { [         2,   quotedbl,  twosuperior,    oneeighth ] };
key <AE03>  { [         3,   sterling, threesuperior,    sterling ] };
key <AE04>  { [         4,     dollar,     EuroSign,   onequarter ] };

key <AC11>  { [apostrophe,         at, dead_circumflex, dead_caron] };
key <TLDE>  { [     grave,    notsign,          bar,          bar ] };

key <BKSL>  { [numbersign, asciitilde,   dead_grave,   dead_breve ] };
key <LSGT>  { [ backslash,        bar,          bar,    brokenbar ] };

key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q,    Escape,       Adiaeresis ]    };
key <AD02> {    [     w,    W,    Delete,            Aring ]    };
key <AD03> {    [     e,    E,    Up,           Eacute ]    };
key <AD04> {    [     r,    R,    Prior,       registered ] };
key <AD05> {    [     t,    T,    Prior,            THORN ] };
key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
key <AD07> {    [     u,    U,    7,           Uacute ] };
key <AD08> {    [     i,    I,    8,           Iacute ] };
key <AD09> {    [     o,    O,    9,           Oacute ] };
key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft   ]   };
key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

key <AC01> {    [     a,    A,    Home,           Aacute ]  };
key <AC02> {    [     s,    S,    Left,          section ]  };
key <AC03> {    [     d,    D,    Down,              ETH ]  };
key <AC04> {    [     f,    F,    Right,                F ] };
key <AC05> {    [     g,    G,    End,                G ]   };
key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
key <AC07> {    [     j,    J,    4,                J ] };
key <AC08> {    [     k,    K,    5,               OE ] };
key <AC09> {    [     l,    L,    6,         Ooblique ] };
key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon,     ntilde,           Ntilde ]   };
key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   at,  dead_acute, dead_diaeresis ]   };

key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z,    BackSpace,               AE ] };
key <AB02> {    [     x,    X,    Insert,                X ]    };
key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
key <AB04> {    [     v,    V,    Next,                V ]  };
key <AB05> {    [     b,    B,    Next,                B ]  };
key <AB06> {    [     n,    N,    0,           Ntilde ] };
key <AB07> {    [     m,    M,    1,               mu ] };
key <AB08> {    [     comma,    less, 2,           less ]   };
key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater, 3,     greater ]   };
key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question    ]   };

include "level3(ralt_switch_multikey)"
};
```

Edit the following file: `sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`

before `</layoutlist>` add this text

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>aa</name>
    <shortDescription>MyLayout (UK)</shortDescription>
    <description>MyLayout (UK)</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
  <variantList/>
```

Now you have a new keyboard layout with this mapping. Add the layout as the first option in your keyboard input methods and you will be able to use it in the terminal, editors, browser...
I have noticed that it doesn't work in some programs like Eclipse. Probably because it has a shorcut defined for them but it works in most places for me.